# Get key from ID in dropdown menu

Tags: foreach, menu, dropdown

First of all I am a real noob but I am trying to get the key from the ID in the dropdown menu.
Now I am getting all the keys from this array. Tried suggestions from google but nothing seems to work for me.
I must be doing something stupid and need some help.
The code I use is as follow

```
$fields['job']['job_job_offer'] = array(
'label'       => 'Select',
'type'        => 'select',
'required'    => false,
'placeholder' => '',
'job_select' => '',
'priority'    => '8',
'options'  => array(
  'Select' => 'Choose one',
  'www.google.com' => 'Google',
  'www.microsoft.com' => 'Microsoft',
   'www.apple.com' => 'Apple',
  )
);

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
echo "$value ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figurate it out myself, this will work for me

```
if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'arrayname', true) === 
'www.microsoft.com') { echo "Microsoft:<br>"; } 
elseif 
(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'arrayname', true) === 
'www.google.com') 
{ echo 'Google'<br>"; }
```